# using contextual filters to filter with relationship

Tags: views

I have articles and issue nodes, where every article is related to an issue. I am trying to create a Views block which shows related Articles. This block should show on on the Article node page.
What I tried was this:

I created a view of Articles. I set the relationship to Entity Reference: Referenced Entity field_article_issue and created a contextual filter on field_article_issue_number (a field in issues) using that relationship. This didn't work, and the block shows nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't show both. When you choose to show articles,  vieuws will select articles from the database using your conditions. Since an issue is not an article, they will not show.

What you probably can do is embed another view in your views header or footer section and display the related issues in that view.

Comment: I edited my post above, I had written something incorrectly. I want to have a view of only Articles, not article. Does this change your answer?

Comment: Ah now I see, it was a block. A block is not capable of reading conditional filters from the url. Your conditional filter should include one of the default options that do work. For instance the `node id from url` option. Can you do anything with that?